# How to read the data in CSV file and create object accordingly by using python console in blender

Tags: python, csv

[image]i have a .csv file like the picture above
i want to read the csv file and be able to pull out the information and make it like something below:

|mode        |   lon            |   lat       |  name      |

|subway     |   116.3572162|   39.8980033|  name1     |

i want to create a mesh according to the information from the csv file
i want the mesh to be in the exact location of the longitude and latitude.
please help , i'm really new to programming :(

Comment: The first part can easily be done in Excel. The second part, if you want the coordinates as vertices bundled into an object, can also easily be done in Excel by creating a [Wavefront OBJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) "space"-separated text file in the format: "v 116.3572162 39.8980033 0 1". (Because this is an Excel, not Blender, solution, I haven't posted it as an answer.)

Comment: @Leorex
hey Leorex :D, thanks for responding . im using blender to make a visualization . so , do you know how to do it? so, by using the python console in the blender , i want to create a uv sphere , and put it at the exact longitude and latitude :)